# Incompleteness of Robinson's Arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic, axioms, incompleteness

In Smith's book about Godel's Theorems a proof is given of incompleteness of Robinson Arithmetic.  It's done by producing a special interpretation of the theory:

1. Domain is $N^* = N \cup \{a,b\}$, a and b are "rogue elements"
2. Sum $+^*$ as follows:
   $$
       a +^* n = a,  n \in N \\
       b +^* n = b,  n \in N \\
       x +^* a = b,  x \in N^* \\
       x +^* b = a,  x \in N^*
   $$
3. From this he concludes  $0 +^* a \neq a$.  How is this reached?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Notice how a tiny bit of formatting transforms your post from barely readable into very clear. You can click the edit timestamp to see how it is done. You can also look into the FAQ on formatting.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see the accepted answer there appears to be the problem statement here. So rather than a duplicate, I think the user apparently has a question about a step in the answer.

Comment: Doesn't the assumption that $a$ and $b$ are distinct, and the third of the four items say $0+^* a=b\neq a$?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the linked duplicate that actually answers the users' question, but I'm not going to get any heartburn about it because I think it might be  already covered by my comment above.

Comment: I'll try to do better with the formatting next time.  Thanks for your help. Agapito